# .out Permission denied using -c directive with g++

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, compilation, g++

I was doing some exercises with makefiles and noticed that a .cpp file I was trying to compile gives me *Permissione Denied* error while trying to exeute the corresponding .out file. I also noticed that using the `-c` directive seems to be the problem. This is because when I do this:

```
singleton_template_main.o: singleton_template_main.cpp singleton.h
       g++ -c singleton_template_main.cpp -o singleton_template_main.out
```

I get the error, but when when I do this:

```
singleton_template_main.o: singleton_template_main.cpp singleton.h
     g++ singleton_template_main.cpp -o singleton_template_main.out
```

I get no error. What could the problem be?

I am using macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 4):

The `-c` flag compiles the code (inhibits linking), producing an intermediate object file - this is not executable. It is also worth noting that in this case, naming the output file as *.out* may not be advisable, the convention for object files are extensions such as *.o* and *.obj* etc.

Removing the `-c` flag causes the compiler to compile and link the code as required, thus producing an executable - and thus it runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you mistyped the output file in your command (`-o singleton_template_main.out` instead of `-o singleton_template_main.o`).  It's better to use `$@` in the command, to avoid such mistakes:

```make
singleton_template_main.o: singleton_template_main.cpp singleton.h
    g++ singleton_template_main.cpp -o "$@"
```

or even

```make
singleton_template_main.o: singleton_template_main.cpp singleton.h
    $(COMPILE.cpp) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<
```

You might need to explicitly link as C++, too:

```make
singleton_template_main: LINK.o = $(LINK.cc)
```